# Android send Gps Data to server without a button press

Tags: android, gps

Currently i have a class that sends data to the server on button press, i am looking to automate this service so that every 4 hrs it send the data to the server without pressing a button. The POST service is currently working in the background , Any pointers?? Do i have to implement a Timer no clue its out of my realm ?? Thanks in Advance !!

```
  Button btnCreateUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    // button click event
    btnCreateUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewUser().execute();
            }
    });
}

class CreateNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)  {
        String lat=latitude, lng=longitude;
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        String newtime =  sdfDateTime.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myText); 
        String newString= (String)username.getText().toString();
        String created_at=newtime;
        String timezone="UTC";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_create_user);
        String responseBody = "";
        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {

            String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString( 
          (username + ":" + created_at +":"+timezone+":"+lat+":"+lng).getBytes(), 
                    Base64.NO_WRAP);

            httppost.setHeader("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials);
            httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json");
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("username", String.valueOf(newString)); 
            obj.put("created_at",String.valueOf(newtime));
            obj.put("timezone", String.valueOf(timezone));
            obj.put("lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
            obj.put("lng", String.valueOf(longitude));
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8"));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

                Log.d("response ok", "Reached Server ok");
                 startActivity(new Intent("com.xxxxx.CLEARSCREEN"));

            } else {
                Log.d("response not ok", "Something went wrong :/");
            }
            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseBody;
    }
```

Comment: you can programmatically click a button with a button.performClick() function. You might want to implement a service for you requirements

Comment: Thanks for that had a look at the button.performClick() i think your right i might have to implement a service any idea what service, timer,background ?

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it by this code :

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();

  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {

    btnCreateUser.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btnCreateUser .performClick();
                }
            }); 
  }
   }, 0, 14400); // for 4 hours
```

Comment: Thanks for That Michael do i implement it instead of the button click?                                                               final Button btnCreateUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
     Timer timer = new Timer();

     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     public void run() {

      btnCreateUser.post(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       btnCreateUser .performClick();
                   }
               }); 
     }
      }, 0, 4400);

Comment: Got that timer working Michael thanks so much, i am going to have to house it in a background activity but its perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AlarmManager` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to start your activity repeatedly in future.

Assuming that the activity you use to collect user data and send them to server is called `YourActivity` just add some static methods as below for scheduling activity start.
You may call the `schedule` method either on application start or from `BOOT_COMPLETE` `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
public static void schedule(Context context, String url,
        long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis) {
    final AlarmManager alarmManager =
            (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, triggerAtMillis,
            intervalMillis, createPendingOperation(context));
}

public static void unschedule(Context context) {
    final AlarmManager alarmManager =
            (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(createPendingOperation(context));
}

private static PendingIntent createPendingOperation(Context context) {
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, new Intent(context, YourActivity.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer will give it a go, Thanks for taking the time to reply.